# Keychain is getting crazy

Tags: ms-office, apple-id, office-365

I am not able to login to my either to OneDrive or my email on outlook.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your Widows account (online) and reset your settings there.

https://account.microsoft.com/account

Keychain is just following orders, and accessing stored information.